# how to do like query in MySQL find second word in string

Tags: mysql, regex, wildcard, sql-like

i want to get like wildcard query to search by second word

here few column data

```
sea food
food restaurant
Chinese food
```

if i search for "foo". it should return

```
sea food
Chinese food
```

how can i do that in MySQL

Comment: so its always 2 words in the string i.e. Chinese food, sea food etc ?

Comment: may be single word or multi. i want to do as truelocal.com.au doing in thier search

Comment: why not use like wild card as `where food_name like '%foo%'`

Comment: It does not work. it also return food restaurant. i want to get those second word start with query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regexp in your sql query .. something like

```
select * from table where col regexp '^[A-Za-z]+\s(foo).*$'
```

EDIT

used your table .. try this ..

```
select id,col from food where col regexp '^[A-Za-z]+ (foo)'
```

Comment: It does not return any row

Comment: here sql script CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `food` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `food` (`id`, `col`) VALUES
(1, 'sea food'),
(2, 'food restaurant'),
(3, 'Chinese food');

Comment: I updated the answer using your create table statement, should work properly now

Comment: thank very much, where i can read document about reg exp. i know little bit. like \s for whitespace etc

Comment: you are welcome Surjit, to test my regular expressions, I use Antix Regex Tester found here .. http://antix.co.uk/Projects/Regex-Tester  and here is a regular expression cheat sheet http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html  hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:-

```
select * from table where food_name like '% foo%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query. This will help in your case.

```
select column-name-list from table-name 
where right(your-desired-column-name,4) = 'food';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it

```
select * from
test
where 
substring_index(food_name,' ',-1) like '%foo%'
AND 
(
   LENGTH(food_name) - LENGTH( substring_index(food_name,' ',-1)) > 0
 )
;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75d4d/6)**